# C++ qt : How to copy/populate item clicked in QlistWidget 1 to QlistWidget2

Tags: c++, qt5

[image: QlistWidgetitemClicked signal should be taken by QlistWidget Slot. What slot should i select from the available option to do so ?]

I want to populate QlistWidgetitemClicked to QlistWidget2.[image]

mainWindows.cpp is as below. I have added four items to it (item1, item2,item3,item4)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->listWidget->addItem("Item1");
    ui->listWidget->addItem("Item2");
    ui->listWidget->addItem("Item3");
    ui->listWidget->addItem("Item4");


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp has default code generated by qt

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h also has default code generated by qt

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

a) Right click on listwidget 1 -> go to slot -> itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)->OK

b) Add below include to mainwindow.h and mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <QListWidgetItem>
```

c) mainwindow.cpp is updates as follows

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QListWidgetItem>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->listWidget->addItem("Item1");
    ui->listWidget->addItem("Item2");
    ui->listWidget->addItem("Item3");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    ui->listWidget_2->addItem(item->clone());
}
```